# Stanford-CoreNLP doesn't empty Memory after running on Threads

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, memory-management, stanford-nlp

While running Stanford CoreNLP on my system it doesn't seem to empty the memory.
Even when using Threads...
I have 2 classes **Testx.java** (Contains main thread) & **Testx2.java** which 
**implements Runnable.**

 
What I would like to do is to empty the memory completely after running the Stanford CoreNLP on String no. 1 as shown in the code below...

And I know it can be done! Because I have seen the Memory usage dip while working on it before(But I didn't keep a back up of that code! :/)
**VM Arguments is -Xmx2048m**

```
public class Testx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "If you had to guess the top city for entertainment & media your first thought would probably be LA.";

    Textx2 x = new Textx2(text);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(x);  
    t1.run();
    t1.interrupt();
```

[Memory usage after **t1** has finished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgEgr.png)
    
// How do I Completely empty the Memory Here before moving on to the next String?

```
    String text2 = "Taylor Swift has a certain attachment to the number 1989 it's the year of her birth.";

    Textx2 x2 = new Textx2(text2);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(x2);  
    t2.run();
    t2.interrupt();
}
```

Testx2.java Code.

```
String text;

public Textx2(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

@Override
public void run() {

            Properties props = new Properties();
            Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
            props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, depparse, sentiment, mention, dcoref, natlog, relation, entitymentions, openie");
            StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
            pipeline.annotate(document);

}
```

[java memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtMB7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try running this line after both threads are done:

```
StanfordCoreNLP.clearAnnotatorPool();
```

Comment: To add to this: the annotators are stored in `SoftReference`s, which means that while they'll show up as used memory, they'll get garbage collected before the program hits an OOM error.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp StanfordCoreNLP.clearAnnotatorPool(); would delete the pipeline! Instantiating it again would take more Memory. Try putting the 2 Threads in a **while(true)** loop and check how the Memory Usage will grow...

Comment: @GaborAngeli I am taking **text1** &  **text2** from a database which contains 1000s of (Long) Strings. I am putting them in a **while(true) loop** & running the pipeline on each one. What happens when a very large String is obtained? After  `t1.run(); t1.interrupt();` will the Annotated String get garbage collected before starting Thread t2?
Also I am working with 16GB of RAM

Comment: I tried running this `int i = 0;
while(i<=4) { 
Run the 2 Threads
i++; 
}` 
and after it finishes 5 Rounds, I checked the memory & it stays at one level (like around 6GB) I don't understand why it doesn't return to its baseline!?

Comment: This size of memory drop you're seeing is almost certainly from the annotators getting garbage collected, rather than from the text you're annotating. If you run `clearAnnotatorPool()` and `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` you should see a relatively consistent drop in memory usage. On softreferences: there is indeed a thrashing condition if you have less memory than it takes to annotated a doc + keep the pipeline, but with 4+ GB you should be safe.

Comment: @GaborAngeli Take a look at this https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtMB7.png (notice memory stays the same after its done.) 
I have created a while loop which takes long strings from the database and and runs the Stanford-CoreNLP model on it. 
After it is done it  keeps checking if a new string of text is added into the DB if so, it then takes the string and processes it in the Stanford Model.
Do I have to **break** out of the loop and stop the main thread to free the memory allocated to javaw.exe?

Comment: You need to clear the annotator pool to clean up the memory from CoreNLP. What you are seeing is expected behavior.